# Wait for x seconds when error thrown with ajax/jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wait

I am populating a database with the following ajax request:

```
function add_ids_to_db(textid) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my_php.php",
    data: {
      textid: textid,
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        add_ids_to_db(textid);
      }, 60000);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log("ids initialized");
    },
   });
}
```

The function just adds a specified integer to a database and is used as `add_ids_to_db(4);`.

Now for [some obscure reason](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:paYge841DWcJ:https://www.godaddy.com/community/Websites-Marketing-Website/Too-many-POST-requests-via-AJAX-crashing-site/td-p/7119+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de) my host (GoDaddy) limits the number of POST requests to 40/minute (if someone has an insight in how to solve this, you'd be my hero) and I get a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`.

Since I need to add several thousands of instances to my database, I would want to avoid an interval.

Instead, I'd like to add a try-catch logic that waits 60 seconds if the request fails and then continues.

How can I do this (either in the ajax request or via another function)?

Any help or alternative solutions to the issue are much appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have added the `setTimeout` in the error event.

My issue now is this: if I run the `add_ids_to_db(something);` function in a loop, it creates duplicate entries (i.e. it does not stop at the error but seems to get out of sync).

E.g. this one would not use each element of `my_array` uniquely but seems to use some multiple times. Ideas why that is?

```
var my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  $(my_array).each(function(i, eli) {
    add_ids_to_db(eli);
});
```

Comment: Remember that this approach won't work if the user closes the browser, so you need some big red warning telling the user not to close the browser. Now for your question, this doesn't seem that complicated, you should show what you have tried to re-issue requests that failed, otherwise, we don't know what part you're having a hard time with. I could post a sample solution but you but SO is not meant to ask for implementations, it's for fixing your existing code.

Comment: Why not post multiple IDs at once?  There should be no problem with posting several thousand IDs in a single request, then handling that on the server side.

Comment: @JuanMendes I've tried to clarify and tried some error handling. Works better but not fully in sync.

Comment: Your $.ajax is asynchronous (as one might reasonably expect).  So by doing this, you're just sending all of your IDs more or less at once, then 60 seconds later resending any that failed.  This is not going to be a functional design and certainly won't get you past any POST/minute limits other than by brute force.  If you want alternate solutions, I suggest either sending multiple IDs in a single request, or breaking your IDs up into chunks of 40 (or less) and sending one chunk per minute.

Comment: What Daniel said; the real solution is to fix your API, no application should be issuing 60 network requests to accomplish a single task. Your current workaround is way too fragile